# calculate distance between two objects in image opencv c++

Tags: opencv

i am measuring distance between two objects in a image using opencv c++.
i have detected two balls with hough transform circle and want to measure distance between them.
so far, used Pythagoras theorem to find distance between two coordinates but not getting close.
d= sq rt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 )
for eg: if distance between two balls is 13 cm then result is 5.6 cm

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure this question makes any sense... "I want to measure the distance between them" - why not just take point one and point two and calculate the difference between the two numbers?

Comment: If you are using the coordinates in the image to calculate the distance, the answer will be in pixels not `cm` so you will have to use the `dpi` also.

Comment: " Measure distance between them means ".. distance between center of detected circles with coordinates using Pythagoras theorem.

Comment: your formula is correct, my guess is you are using the hough coordinates and not the ones from your original image.

Answer (score 0):

To measure the distance between objects in an image you will have to look into camera calibration concept.

And as said by Mark Setchell the distance will be in pixels if you do not do the calibration and 2D point  to 3D point transformation.

Comment: Hi Anubhav,
i had looked into camera calibration concept but still not able to determine the relation between the camera’s natural units(pixel) and the real world units(mm) so that i could calculate distance between two balls. Could you tell me what is the relation between them.
thanks